# Получение данных из JSON документа

Tags: javascript, json, api

Хочу достать текст анекдота через данный API, но JSON приходит в формате [{"text:"abcdefgh"}] и из-за [] parse не работает, как получить нужные данные?

```
  const getJoke = {

            api: "http://www.umori.li/api/get?site=bash.im&name=bash&num=1",

            jokeFunction : function(){
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();   
                var url = getJoke.api;
                ajax.open("GET", url, true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                        const readyJoke = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                        console.log(readyJoke);

                    }
                };
                ajax.send(null);
            }  
        };
        getJoke.jokeFunction();
```

Comment: [] = массив, кто вам сказал что изза него парс не работает ?

Comment: Да, не так выразился он работает и выдает [ Object [JSON] {} ] и тут меня стопорит, я совсем зеленый в JS и не могу понять, что дальше делать с этой конструкцией, заранее благо дарю.

Comment: Прочитайте про массив. Вам надо получить первый элемент массива и тогда сможете работать уже с объектом.

Comment: @TheCl если у вас в `ajax.responseText` и правда хранится такая строка :   `'[{"text":"abcdefgh"}]'` , то все с ней в порядке и в консоль должен выводиться массив.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так`
         const getJoke = {

```
        api: "http://www.umori.li/api/get?site=bash.im&name=bash&num=1",

        jokeFunction : function(){
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();   
            var url = getJoke.api;
            ajax.open("GET", url, true);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                    const readyJoke = ajax.responseText[0];
                    console.log(readyJoke);

                }
            };
            ajax.send(null);
        }  
    };
    getJoke.jokeFunction();`
```